# iOS: Relative Positioning like Android's layouts

Tags: android, iphone, ios, android-layout, interface-builder

Is there any way position views relative to each other like you can with Android layouts?

Example: You have two UILabels that are dynamically set to strings of variable length, one above the other, and you want the bottom label to appear directly below the last line of the top label, regardless of how many lines the top label ends up having.

Another example: Same situation as above, but one of the labels is sometimes hidden. You want the resulting label(s) to be centered vertically in the parent, regardless of whether it's one label or two labels.

Android's Linear Layout and Relative Layout make this very easy to do, but I can't figure out how to do this is iOS. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to do this using AutoLayout in iOS6. For an application that should run in iOS before 6.0, you have to do it by yourself, but this is not very complicated.

**Actually I have implemented [a class to do this](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHStackView)** (that's a long time ago, I hope it still works, but there is no reason not to). This **`OHStackView`** class is a subclass of `UIView` that automatically layout its subviews horizontally or vertically to stack or align them.

You can ask `OHStackView` to stack its subviews horizontally or vertically (one above the other, etc), or align their top/bottom/left/right borders or their centers, and even specify a padding between each subviews. Each time one of the subview changes its frame or size, `OHStackView` will automatically relayout all depending views to realign everything.
*(E.g with your two UILabels, a simple call to `sizeToFit` on your labels to make them adjust their size to their content will relayout everything around automagically)*

There is an example project provided so feel free to test it.

*Note: IIRC, my subclass does not take the "hidden" property of the subviews into account. But you can easily add support to this behavior by adding a condition like `if (v.hidden) continue;` in the `for` loop of its `layoutSubview` implementation to only take non-hidden views into account in the layout algorithm.*

HTH

Comment: AutoLayout sounds like what I need. I can't believe it's only now being added!

Comment: Yes, but I guess that's mainly because iPhone devices all have the same screen size, contrary to Android devices. So in general you don't need layouts as in Android, you can position your content once for all. Well at least until now, but as the future iPhone 5 may have a different screen size than its predecessor, AutoLayout will begin to be more needed. Anyway, my OHStackView can still do the job for applications that needs to be compatible with iOS before 6.0

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching  if it's possible for a long time. As far as i can tell, it's not possible for now. I don't remember where i read this,but it will be possible with ios6. Instead of using Android's Linear Layout,you can use `sizeWithFont` method to detect size of your `UILabel`,then you can set their frame to position them.First,you need to set their text of course to find their size according to their font family. Another thing you can use is `sizeToFit` method. Unfortunately,i don't know how to use it. You can give a shot,though. At that time,i found this.Maybe ,you can use it https://github.com/scalessec/CSLinearLayoutView